# combine lists to make one list that has each element a sum of the individual elements

Tags: python

I have 3 lists:

```
['1','2']

['a','b','c']

['X','Y']
```

and the result I am looking to get:

```
['1aX','1bX','1cX','2aX','2bX','2cX','1aY','1bY','1cY','2aY','2bY','2cY']
```

is there a way to set this up quickly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: I believe this operation is called the cartesian product of sets.  Felix is a ninja.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `itertools.product()`:

```
map("".join, itertools.product(list1, list2, list3))
```

Comment: The results will be in a different order than the OP specified though. (Which might not really matter of course.)

Comment: @millimoose doubt order is important - if so, it would have been specified!

Comment: Thanks for the awesome responses. I'm new to python and this forum. The order is actually important. But I already learned so much from what has been posted here, so I appreciate this answer.

Comment: @JonClements: *Should*, not *would*. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x,y,z=['1','2'],['a','b','c'],['x','y']
>>> s=[a+b+c for c in z for a in x for b in y]
>>> s
['1ax', '1bx', '1cx', '2ax', '2bx', '2cx', '1ay', '1by', '1cy', '2ay', '2by', '2cy']
```

This way you can choose the order you want

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact result that you specified, you can use the following:

```
import operator
import itertools

list1 = ['1','2']
list2 = ['a','b','c']
list3 = ['X','Y']
getter = operator.itemgetter(1, 2, 0)
result = [''.join(getter(seq)) for seq in itertools.product(list3, list1, list2)]
```

The final argument to `itertools.product()` will be the first to change, so based on your example output we want `list2` to be last, then `list1`, and then `list3`, since first the middle element advances, then the first element, then the last.  The `operator.itemgetter()` call is used to reorder the elements so that the element from `list1` comes first, etc.

I find list comprehensions easier to read here, but here is a one-line alternative that uses `map()`:

```
map(''.join, map(operator.itemgetter(1, 2, 0), itertools.product(list3, list1, list2)))
```

(You could do the list comprehension in one line as well, but you shouldn't because then the `operator.itemgetter()` call would be executed on each iteration)